# Passing Function parameter to another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I a learning react and stuck at this place. I am creating an app In which user will see a list of product with different id and name. I have created another component in which the detail of the product will open . I am collection the id and value of the particular product in my addList component by onClick function. And now i want to send those value in DetailList component so that i can show the detail of that particular product.

A roadmap like

Add list -> (user click on a product) -> id and name of the product passes to the DetailList component -> Detail list component open by fetching the product detail.

Here is my code of Add list component

```
    export default class Addlist extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        posts : []
      }
    }
    
      passToDetailList(id) {
          console.log( id)
    }
    
      async componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:80/get_add_list.php')
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response);
              this.setState({posts: response.data})
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error); 
            })
        } 
        
        render() {
          const { posts } = this.state;
            //  JSON.parse(posts)
            return (
              <Fragment>
               <div className="container" id="listOfAdd">
                      
              <ul className="addUl">
            {
              posts.map(post => {
                return (
                <li key={post.id}>
                   <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                      <img src={trialImage}  alt=""></img>
                    </div> {/* min col  end */}
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                <b><h2>{post.add_title}</h2></b>
                      
                     

    {/* This button is clicked by user to view detail of that particular product */}
                        <button onClick={() => this.passToDetailList(post.id)}>VIEW</button>
    
                    </div> {/* min col  end */}
                  </div> {/* row end */}
                  
                  </li> 
                );
              })}
                      
     
             </ul>
           </div>{/* container end */}
       </Fragment>
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the data through the routes  -

```
<Route path="/details/:id" component={DetailList} /> // router config

passToDetailList(id) {
     this.props.history.push('/details/'+id)
}
```

and then in the DetailList Component, you can access the value through -

```
console.log(this.props.match.params.id) - //here is the passed product Id
```

Comment: I have my id as a parameter for a function. As we can not use backticks  in path so how would i pass that variable in path.

Comment: passToDetailList(id) {
         this.props.history.push('/details/'+id)
    }
while naviagiting you can pass the id

Comment: Can you just tell is there a case if i want to send name and id both following this method . Does this works path="/details/:id/:name

Comment: yes if you want to read more about it check this link: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-pass-multiple-route-parameters-in-a-react-url-path-4b919de0abbe

Answer (score 1):

You need to elevate the `state` for `id` to a common parent between `AddList` and `DetailList` and then create a function in parent component to set the `id` and pass the `id` and `setId` function to your `AddList` Component through `props` , then just use `setId` function to set the `id` state in `passToDetailList` function.

finally you can use the `id` in your `DetailList` Component to fetch its details

so Here is how your `AddList` Component would look like:

```
export default class Addlist extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  passToDetailList(id) {
    this.props.setId(id);
  }

  // The rest of your code
}
```

and here is how your `DetailList` Component will look like:

```
export default class DetailList extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    // Use the id to fetch its details
    console.log(this.props.id)
  }
}
```

and finally here is your `CommonParent` Component:

```
export default class CommonParent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: ''
    };
    this.setId = this.setId.bind(this);
  }

  setId(id){
    this.setState({
      id
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <>
        <AddList setId={this.setId} />
        <DetailList id={this.state.id} />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

if your Components are very far from each other in component tree you can use `react context` or `redux` for handling `id` state

Comment: can you please share me the link where i can read more about this. That would be a lot of help. Also after the user click the button of the it automatically direct to DetailList component. How would i achieve this. I am thinking of using window.location method. Is there something diffrent i can use in that case ?

Comment: I thought you are using the ```AddList``` and ```DetailList``` Components at the same time. this doesn't work for you. if you are using react router use ```Route``` Component as @Dlucidone said

Comment: No issue, this is extra knowledge for me . Thankyou for sharing

Comment: You're Welcome, here is the official Doc about Lifting the State: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Can you please answer my last ccomment in the above answer